# Finding a good parametric form for a model

Tags: mathematical-modeling

Hello
I am trying to model the relationship between two variables, say x and y.  I have a number of subjects - for each subjectm I have a number of x and corresponding y, both of which are always positive.  This data tends to be very sparse.  There are some problem specific constraints:
1) y(0) = 0 (or very close to it)
2) y is increasing as a function of x
3) y' is decreasing as a function of x

This is rather nebulous, but I have a feeling that the most important difference between subjects is in the height of the curve, not in the slope.  Because of the sparsity, I think I can get away with forcing each subject to have the same "slope" (perhaps at a specified x), but allowing the height to vary.  I have been playing around with various sorts of logistic functions, but the asymptote isn't really justifiable.  I have also been looking at things like a*log(x+b), but this doesn't really conform to the intuition delineated above.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: As non-expert said, if we could look at the graph we might be able to help more.

Answer (score 1):

(This is supposed to be a comment.)

I would say that without knowing the physical process(es) that generated the $y$'s for each corresponding $x$'s, any number of functions would be admissible. Barring that, one usually graphs the data first before even thinking about models...

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I don't really know much about the physical process.  I have plotted the data, but for each subject it is extremely noisy.  This is why I am trying to just get something off the ground.  To clarify a bit - I am looking for a model that has maybe 1 parameter that controls steepness, 1 that controls height, and maybe one or two others.

Comment: Maybe you can edit your post to show that noisy graph you speak of, and then we can start from there.

Answer (score 0):

First, draw a distinction between what you expect and what you measure.

Since the expectations can't sculpt a functional form, investigate a generic method like polynomial approximation. Then you can look at the result and see how well it matches your expectations.

Start with a set of $m$ measurements $\left\{ x_{k}, y_{k} \right\}_{k=1}^{m}$ and $d$th order approximation.

**Model**

$$
 y(x) = a_{0} + \sum_{\mu=1}^{d} a_{\mu} x^{\mu}
$$

**Linear system**

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{A} a &= y \\
%
\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
  1 & x_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & \dots & x_{1}^{d} \\
  1 & x_{2} & x_{2}^{2} & \dots & x_{2}^{d} \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
  1 & x_{m} & x_{m}^{2} & \dots & x_{m}^{d} \\
\end{array} \right]
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  a_{0} \\ a_{1} \\ \vdots \\ a_{d}
\end{array} \right]
%
&=
%
\left[ \begin{array}{c}
  y_{1} \\ y_{2} \\ \vdots \\ y_{m}
\end{array} \right]
%
\end{align}
$$

**Least squares solution**

The least squares solution is
$$
 a_{LS} = \mathbf{A}^{+}b +
\left(
 \mathbf{I}_{d+1} - \mathbf{A}^{+} \mathbf{A}
\right) z, \quad z \in \mathbb{C}^{d+1}
$$